# Json.Net serialization of IEnumerable with TypeNameHandling=auto

Tags: c#, json.net

According to [Json.Net documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm) all `IEnumerable` types should be serialized as json array.

So I expect the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

to be serialized as:

```
{
    "Values": []
}
```

The problem is that when I use `TypeNameHandling=Auto` I get:

```
{
    "Values": {
        "$type": "System.String[], mscorlib",
        "$values": []
    }
}
```

I need `TypeNameHandling=Auto` for other properties but I expect `IEnumerable` to use the default serialization. Other types (`IList` for example) works as expected.

It is a bug or I missing something?

Here the full code to reproduce the problem:

```
    [Test]
    public void Newtonsoft_serialize_list_and_enumerable()
    {
        var target = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        };

        var myEvent = new MyClass
        {
            Values = new string[0]
        };

        var builder = new StringWriter();
        target.Serialize(builder, myEvent);
        var json = JObject.Parse(builder.ToString());

        Assert.AreEqual(JTokenType.Array, json["Values"].Type);
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using Newtonsoft 7.0.1.

**UPDATE**:
Here another test using more types:

```
    [Test]
    public void Newtonsoft_serialize_list_and_enumerable()
    {
        var target = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        };

        var myEvent = new MyClass
        {
            Values1 = new string[0],
            Values2 = new List<string>(),
            Values3 = new string[0],
            Values4 = new List<string>(),
            Values5 = new string[0]
        };

        var builder = new StringWriter();
        target.Serialize(builder, myEvent);
        var json = builder.ToString();
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Values1 { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Values2 { get; set; }
        public IList<string> Values3 { get; set; }
        public IList<string> Values4 { get; set; }
        public string[] Values5 { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the results:

```
{
    "Values1": {
        "$type": "System.String[], mscorlib",
        "$values": []
    },
    "Values2": [],
    "Values3": {
        "$type": "System.String[], mscorlib",
        "$values": []
    },
    "Values4": [],
    "Values5": []
}
```

Again I don't understand why I get different results depending on the combination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default automatic behaviour of Json.Net, when deserializing into an `IEnumerable` or `IList` field, is to create a `List` instance. If you assign an `Array` instance, then the only way to restore your object to it original instance state is for Json.Net to add the `$type` meta data, which is what you are seeing. *i.e. there are many ways to deserialize into an `IEnumerable` field.*

By using a `List<string>` instance:

```
var myEvent = new MyClass
{
    Values = new List<string>(),
};
```

with:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

results in (when serialized):

```
{"Values":["hello"]}
```

Also, if you use an explicit constructable type or use the default List, then Json.Net will use that and omit `$type`;

For instance:

```
string[] Values { get; set; } = new string[0]; // not needed
IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; } = new string[0]; //$type needed
IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; } = new Stack<string>(); //$type needed
IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string>; // not needed
List<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string>; // not needed

ObservableCollection<string> Values { get; set; } = 
    new ObservableCollection<string>(); // not needed
```

Comment: Thanks, I will probably use this solution. But I think it is a bug, because the behavior should be the same for all types, instead I get different results depending on the fact if I use `List` or `array`.

Comment: For me, that is incorrect. If you set `new string[0]` to an `IList` field, you will get the same behaviour. As I've pointed out, the default deserialisation behavour is to create a `List` instance for  the `Enumerable` and `IList` interface fields. If you specify an explicit object type, it will use that instead; but there are many ways to instantiate an `IEnumerable`. the only way to know exactly what instance you used, if you go against the default, is to add the `$type` meta-data

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug but this is expected behavior. You are setting the `TypeNameHandling` globally. Instead of globally setting the type name handling you can mark properties with attribute like below to avoid them being included for setting `TypeNameHandling.Auto`:

```
[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]
```

Here's a sample:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        // Indicate the property not to apply any type handling
        [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling=TypeNameHandling.None)]
        public IList<string> Values { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

This will give you desired result without getting affected by any `TypeNameHandling` setting declared globally.

Comment: Usually I don't like to insert serialization attributes in my code, but eventually this can be a good solution. But I don't understand why for other types the behavior is different. For example if I declare the property as IList<T> and set it to a List<T>. I think it is a bug...

Comment: This is behavior to support correct deserialization of derived types. When you declare it global then its applied to all properties. This is why the support for TypeNameHandling is provided as property attributes. It can be done other way around as well e.g. Mark properties which needs special TypeHandling to Auto and not using global setting at all.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but why IList has a different behavior? And the documentation seems to confirm my expectations.

Comment: Can you share the link? cuz I confirmed it by running the code on my machine both had same outcome with IList and IEnumerable.

Comment: I have updated the question with the more cases. I don't understand why the behavior is different between `array` and `List`. Here the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm). Eventually I expect to always have a wrapped object when the type don't match, but this is not the case.