# Override newtonsoft.json serialization in ASP.NET Core to make the typeNameHandling to be Auto only for objects and not arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

My issue is that I need some `$type` on my serialized json, I have some subclasses and it's very useful for me.

This is my startup

```
services.AddTransient<Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>, App_Start.MvcJsonOptionsSetup>();
services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
        .AddControllersAsServices();

internal class MvcJsonOptionsSetup : IConfigureOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _provider;

   public MvcJsonOptionsSetup(IHttpContextAccessor provider)
   {
   }

   public MvcJsonOptionsSetup(IHttpContextAccessor provider)
   {
       _provider = provider;
   }

   public Func<IServiceProvider> GetProvider()
   {
       return () => _provider.HttpContext?.RequestServices;
   }

   public override void Configure(MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions options)
   {
       options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
       options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
       options.SerializerSettings.ConfigureRepositoryForJson<EntidadeBase>(GetProvider());
       options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto;
    }
}
```

The problem is with the arrays; I would like to never put the `$values`, but sometimes the return type is not the same.

Did anyone make some extension that would be `TypeNAmeHandling.Auto` except for arrays?

For example, I use the kendo grid, and the return is this:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Model.Entity, Model]], System.Private.CoreLib",
    "$values": [
        ...
    ]
  },
  "Groups": null,
  "Aggregates": null,
  "Total": 4,
  "Errors": null
}
```

And I would like it as this

```
{
  "Data":  [
        ...
    ]
  ,
  "Groups": null,
  "Aggregates": null,
  "Total": 4,
  "Errors": null
}
```

I'm not using the

```
TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Objects
```

to make the result even simpler, I would like to return only if the type is a subclass.

This is the result class

```
public class DataSourceResult
{
    public IEnumerable Data { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable Groups { get; set; }
    public object Aggregates { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public object Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, note that I can't put attributes (such as `[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling=TypeNameHandling.None)]`) in all classes, I mean, there are libraries that I use and can't change, I was looking for something that I could override the newtonsoft serializer and check if was array and ignore the typeNamehandling property.

Comment: How is `Data` declared?  Is it just `object` or `dynamic` or is it something assignable to `IEnumerable`?  I.e. is the fact that `Data` is some sort of collection or enumerable known at compile time -- with only the precise, concrete collection type left unknown?

Comment: I added the result class @dbc

Comment: Easiest way to prevent `Data` from being serialized with type information is to mark it with `[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling=TypeNameHandling.None)]` as shown in [this specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34663749/37441820) by [vendettamit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881798/vendettamit) to [Json.Net serialization of IEnumerable with TypeNameHandling=auto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34662966/3744182). Is that sufficient for your needs, or do you need some way to mark `IEnumerable` properties with `[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling=TypeNameHandling.None)]` automatically via settings?

Comment: I looked at this, my problem is that I can't put attributes in all classes, I mean, there are libraries that I use and can't change, I was looking for something that I could override the newtonsoft serializer and check if was array and ignore the typeNamehandling property

Comment: OK.  As long as the properties are declared as `IEnumerable` or it can be done with a custom contract resolver.  Will add an answer shortly.  But the choice of whether to emit type information is based on the type of the property, not the type of the referenced object.  If you need to suppress type information for `object` properties that happen to refer to collections a more complex solution will be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Json.NET there is no way to enable or disable emission of type information based purely on the concrete type of the item being serialized.  Instead, emission of type information is controlled by the member or collection that refers to the item being serialized.<sup>*</sup>

As long as those members (or collection items) are declared to be something assignable from `IEnumerable`, you can suppress type information using a custom contract resolver such as the following:

```
public class SuppressCollectionTypeNamesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    internal static TypeNameHandling? RemoveCollectionTypenameHandling(TypeNameHandling? typeNameHandling, Type valueType)
        => typeNameHandling ?? (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(valueType) && valueType != typeof(string) ? TypeNameHandling.None : typeNameHandling);

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.TypeNameHandling = RemoveCollectionTypenameHandling(property.TypeNameHandling, property.PropertyType);
        return property;
    }

    protected override JsonArrayContract CreateArrayContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);
        contract.ItemTypeNameHandling = RemoveCollectionTypenameHandling(contract.ItemTypeNameHandling, contract.CollectionItemType);
        return contract;
    }
}
```

And use it in place of `DefaultContractResolver` like so:

```
options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new SuppressCollectionTypeNamesContractResolver();
```

Note that Newtonsoft [recommends caching custom resolvers statically for best performance](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver).

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FsFORz).

If you might have members declared as `object` or `dynamic` and still need to suppress type information in cases where their values are collections, you will have to use a custom converter such as the following:

```
public class SuppressCollectionTypeNamesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    static readonly IContractResolver globalDefaultResolver = new JsonSerializer().ContractResolver;
    IContractResolver resolver;
    
    public SuppressCollectionTypeNamesConverter() : this(globalDefaultResolver) { }
    public SuppressCollectionTypeNamesConverter(IContractResolver resolver) => this.resolver = resolver ?? globalDefaultResolver;
    
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) && objectType != typeof(string) && resolver.ResolveContract(objectType) is JsonArrayContract;

    public override bool CanRead => false;      
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();        

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contract = (JsonArrayContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());
        var itemType = contract.CollectionItemType;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (object item in ((IEnumerable)value))
        {
            if (contract.ItemTypeNameHandling == TypeNameHandling.None)
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
            else
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item, itemType);
        }
        
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

And add it to options as follows:

```
options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new SuppressCollectionTypeNamesConverter());
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QThmtg).

---

<sup>* <sub>This can be confirmed from the reference source for [`JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/52e257ee57899296d81a868b32300f0b3cfeacbe/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L680) which calls [`JsonSerializerInternalWriter.ShouldWriteType()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/52e257ee57899296d81a868b32300f0b3cfeacbe/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L999)</sub></sup>

Comment: this looks amazing, I'll try it and come back to mark as answer